# How to loop a sound a different number of times at set intervals - android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I've done a little with android in the past, but this is the first time I've touched it in over a year and I've been stuck on this problem since yesterday.

I'm working on a project with someone and I need to play a sound a certain number of times at set intervals. (For example, play once after one minute, twice after two minutes, three times after three minutes, and on and on). I can get the sound to play at whatever interval, that's not an issue, but I can't figure out how to get it to play the correct number of times at each interval. It either ends up looping infinitely, playing once each time the interval is up or playing once and stopping.

Tried TimerTask, switched to Handler/Runnable, tried using a for loop and using an if statement with counter. After two evenings of multiple attempts, hours of research and my limited experience, this is the one problem I've run into that I haven't been able to figure out.

Here's the code I've currently got in for this particular feature. I'm having issues with the Runnable tenMinChime and OnCompletionListener chimeCompletion. Any guidance at all is very appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView chimeOn, chimeOff;
Handler chimeHandler = new Handler();
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener chimeCompletion;
MediaPlayer cp;
int chimeCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (screen == 1) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chimeOn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chimeOn);
    chimeOff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chimeOff);
    chimeOn.setTextColor(0xFFbebebe);
    chimeOff.setTextColor(0xFF000000);

    cp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.placeholder_chime);

    chimeOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chime == 0) {
                chimeOn.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                chimeOff.setTextColor(0xFFbebebe);
                handler2.postDelayed(tenMinChime, 5000);
                chime = 1;
            }
        }
    });

    chimeOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chime == 1) {
                chimeOff.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                chimeOn.setTextColor(0xFFbebebe);
                handler2.removeCallbacks(tenMinChime);
                chime = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    chimeCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        int count = 0;
        int maxCount = chimeCount;
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if(count < maxCount) {
                count++;
                cp.seekTo(0);
                cp.start();
                cp.setOnCompletionListener(chimeCompletion);
            }
        }
    };

public Runnable tenMinChime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        chimeCount+=1;
        cp.start();
        cp.setOnCompletionListener(chimeCompletion);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solves your issue ?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView chimeOn, chimeOff;
    Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener chimeCompletion;
    MediaPlayer cp;
    int chimeCount = 0;
    int mPlayCount=0;
    int mMaxPlayCount=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (screen == 1) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chimeOn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chimeOn);
        chimeOff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chimeOff);
        chimeOn.setTextColor(0xFFbebebe);
        chimeOff.setTextColor(0xFF000000);

        cp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.placeholder_chime);

        chimeOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (chime == 0) {
                    chimeOn.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                    chimeOff.setTextColor(0xFFbebebe);
                    handler2.postDelayed(tenMinChime, 5000);
                    chime = 1;
                }
            }
        });

        chimeOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (chime == 1) {
                    chimeOff.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                    chimeOn.setTextColor(0xFFbebebe);
                    handler2.removeCallbacks(tenMinChime);
                    cp.setOnCompletionListener(null);
                    chime = 0;
                    mMaxPlayCount=0;
                    mPlayCount=0;

                }
            }
        });

        chimeCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(mPlayCount < mMaxPlayCount) {
                    mPlayCount++;
                    cp.seekTo(0);
                    cp.start();
                }
            }
        };

    public Runnable tenMinChime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mPlayCount=0;
            mMaxPlayCount= 3;
            cp.setOnCompletionListener(chimeCompletion);
            cp.start();
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm still getting one play per interval with this, but I appreciate your help!
I actually got it working using a SoundPool, but now I don't have access to OnCompletionListener, which is posing another problem.